# How to access connection string stored in web config file of client application inside back end class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a client asp.net project whose logic is processed in BL and DAL class library projects in same solution. This works perfectly fine.

Now I tried to upgrade my project and use WCF services to communicate between client application and server side logic. I made another solution and added WCF service and BL and DAL class library project in that solution, but I am not able to access the connection string stored in web.config file of client application.
I tried to add connection string in web.config file of WCF service project's web.config file but same issue continues.

I added references of BL in service project and DAL class library in BL class library. The structure of my ServiceTestOnline ie server side logic solution looks as below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried to read the connection string from the config file and what error occured?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the connection string to the classes in the class library from the web site.

This is a better choice than trying to get the information directly from the configuration file, as otherwise you will have a dependency on the configuration file existing with the exact right key (making testing the class somewhat harder).

See [this blog post](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/configuration-settings-are-a-dependency-that-should-be-injected) for arguments against accessing configuration directly (which is very commonly done, but is not best practice).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your WCF projects are new projects.  You will need to copy the connection string in each WCF project.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this if you are using native ADO.Net to implement your DL (Data Layer)

First, you have to have the ConnectionString added in your web.config file of your ServiceAPI Project correctly.

and the class libraries need to be referenced correctly (Add Reference > Projects > select your relevant class library project to reference)

if you have done referencing correctly, the primary project will collect all the needed references at one location, that's mean your class library is trying to read the connection or configurations mostly from primary project's configuration file,

to make it work,

. Reference the System.Configuration to your DL.
. and you can read connection string like

```
var ConnectioString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: unable to use ConfigurationManager class even after including System.Configuration namespace. Error:-The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: above error was displayed when I was trying to use ConfigurationManager in DAL class library.

Comment: please use in your class `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my first comment that I included System.Configuration namespace @Dilan Wickramarathna